# Why tag P popups the DIV when contains DIV?

Tags: html, css

## [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/mewejamoco/edit?html,css,output)

## HTML

```
<p>
  <div>123</div>
</p>
```

## CSS

```
p div{
  background:#f00;
}
```

I have a strange issue. When I code a structure as following HTML. Actually, User agent(browser) parse the code to :

```
<p></p><div>123</div>
```

So, the css code is ineffective.you can check it out in [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/mewejamoco/edit?html,css,output).I want to know what the reason about this behavior and whether there are another similar tags have this behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a combination of two features of HTML.

First, the `p` element is not allowed to contain a `div` element. The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) gives its content model as "Phrasing content" which does not include `div` elements.

Second, the end tag for the `p` element is optional. (See *tag omission* under the above link to the spec)

```
<p>    <!-- Start P element -->
<div>  <!-- Start DIV element. Implicitly end P element -->
123    <!-- Add text node -->
</div> <!-- End DIV element -->
</p>   <!-- No open P element so this is discarded by the parser -->
```

Comment: But if `a` contains `div`. It's ok. I want to know whether there is a nature reason to define the tag behavior or not. Is it about the W3C draft?

Comment: The two features described in the answer have been true for as long as HTML has had paragraphs and divs, this has nothing to do with draft status. Anchors being allowed to contain div elements is new for HTML 5, but the end tag for anchors has never been optional so browsers performed error recovery in a way that is consistent with the HTML 5 spec.

Comment: The problem is that you're building 'tag soup'. Because you are putting a not allowed element inside a `<p>` the browser is guessing you aren't using it as a block element, and as a paragraph separator instead - makes sense, as it never encountered a `</p>` tag before the new block level element was found. Write valid HTML and all will be fine. As @Quentin correctly notes your source code has been invalid since the day `div`'s were introduced late last century.